# var late don't woking

Tags: ios, swift

the text must be red when the variable beats == "true"

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! InstallmentTableViewCell

        if self.switchInstallmentToPay == true {
            if let installment = PaymentManager.paymentPlan?.unpaidInstallments![indexPath.row] {
                if let id = installment.id, let paymentDue = installment.paymentDue, let description = installment.numberDescription, let method = installment.paymentMethodDescription, let expectedPayment = installment.expectedPayment, let actualPayment = installment.actualPayment, let payable = installment.payable, let late = installment.late {
                    cell.load(id: id, paymentDue: paymentDue, description: description, method: method, expectedPayment: expectedPayment, actualPayment: actualPayment, payable: payable, late: late)
                    if installment.payable! {
                        cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
                        cell.tintColor = UIColor.lighterGray
                        cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                        if installment.late! {
                            cell.lbDescription.textColor = UIColor.danger // not working
                        }

                    }else{
                        cell.accessoryType = .none
                        //cell.tintColor = UIColor.lightGray
                        cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
                    }
                }
            }
        }else{
            if let installment = PaymentManager.paymentPlan?.paidInstallments![indexPath.row] {
                if let id = installment.id, let paymentDue = installment.paymentDue, let description = installment.numberDescription, let method = installment.paymentMethodDescription, let expectedPayment = installment.expectedPayment, let actualPayment = installment.actualPayment, let payable = installment.payable, let late = installment.late {
                    cell.load(id: id, paymentDue: paymentDue, description: description, method: method, expectedPayment: expectedPayment, actualPayment: actualPayment, payable: payable, late: late)
                    cell.accessoryType = .none
                    cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

                    cell.lbDescription.textColor = UIColor.black // not working

                cell.tintColor = UIColor.lighterGray
            }
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: add breakpoint to know whether control reaches that line

Comment: Is the `cell.lbDescription` outlet hooked up properly in the storyboard/xib?

Comment: I added an else, it looks like it's working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is difficult to read, and there's a lot of redundancy. If you're using a storyboard, I suggest making *separate* dynamic cells for the paid and unpaid installments. *Both* cells' class type can stay `InstallmentTableViewCell`, as you're just duplicating the cells' *views*, not their logic. The various elements' colors & styles can be set right in the storyboard's cell prototype, and then your `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:indexPath)` can be simplified to just

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellID = switchInstallmentToPay ? "unpaidCell" : "paidCell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellID, for: indexPath) as! InstallmentTableViewCell
    cell.load(...)

    return cell
}
```

I would also recommend changing `cell.load()` to take an `installment` argument and setting the cells' properties there instead of cluttering the caller with multiple `if let`s.